# How to create table with inheritance - sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, inheritance

I am trying to create a WebUser class in my ASP.Net core site that inherits the IdentityUser class but unsure how to replicate this in the database.

I've tried doing something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE WebUser (
    PoEmail nvarchar(50),
    RemEmail nvarchar(50),
    HsbEmail nvarchar(50),
    GrEmail nvarchar(50)
) INHERIT (dbo.AspNetUser);
```

as per a website I was looking at but this didnt work - I'm using sqlserver.

Comment: use entity framework and inherit IdentityUser in the WebUser model and let entity framework do the rest of the work

Comment: Table inheritance is a highly controversial **non-standard** feature. Tables aren't types, they are *relations* between values. PostgreSQL is probably the only database that has `INHERITS`

Comment: What is the *actual* problem? Are you trying to customize ASP.NET Identity's user type? You don't need inheritance in the database for that. You only need to create the table with the columns you want and tell Identity to use the new class

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes i'm trying to customize it - I need the database to store more than one email address and the IdentityUser only has one

Comment: Then add the column to the database and the property to the type. You don't need inheritance

Comment: Customizing the user type is [described in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-user-data) in the [Custom User Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-user-data) section

Comment: Ok sorry im not familiar with this...